# Drawing/Calculating an area with an angle in Google's object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I want to use some parking lot images of cars in Google's object detection API(https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). The cars are usually not portrayed as a straight box but more of a box that is turned 45 degrees to either side, causing the x and y coordinates to lay in a diagonal line instead of straight line. Normally, just using a box would work but the cars are quite close to each other which is why I need to change it.

In the API they use ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax to draw the boxes for the objects in the images. So my question is, can I change it so the code does the calculations and draws the box out of the defined by 4 points in order to used an angled box? And if possible... how?

I want to draw the box like the one to the left.[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be simpler to rotate your images instead?

Comment: There are several cars in the image rotated in different directions.